# Ansible task to strip out data from a file

Tags: shell, ansible

A file has the following contents

```
com.dkr.container.id=a43019cc-d4a4-4acb-83dd-defd76443c6a
com.dkr.container.account=12HJB
```

I need to fetch `a43019cc-d4a4-4acb-83dd-defd76443c6a` and write it to a variable using an Ansible task. This value need to be passed to other tasks in the same Ansible file.

Can someone show me the required task to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the job for the *ini* lookup plugin. See

```sh
shell> ansible-doc -t lookup ini
```

For example, given the file

```sh
shell> cat container.properties 
com.dkr.container.id=a43019cc-d4a4-4acb-83dd-defd76443c6a
com.dkr.container.account=12HJB
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        id: "{{ lookup('ini', 'com.dkr.container.id
                type=properties
                file=container.properties') }}"
    - debug:
        var: id
```

gives

```yaml
  id: a43019cc-d4a4-4acb-83dd-defd76443c6a
```

The [*lookup plugins*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html) work on the controller only. If the file is at the remote host [*fetch*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html) it, e.g. given the file

```sh
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat container.properties
com.dkr.container.id=a43019cc-d4a4-4acb-83dd-defd76443c6a
com.dkr.container.account=12HJB
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: test_11
  tasks:
    - fetch:
        src: container.properties
        dest: /tmp/fetched
    - set_fact:
        id: "{{ lookup('ini', 'com.dkr.container.id
                type=properties
                file=/tmp/fetched/{{ inventory_hostname }}/container.properties') }}"
    - debug:
        var: id
```

gives the same result

```yaml
  id: a43019cc-d4a4-4acb-83dd-defd76443c6a
```

The playbook above is idempotent. The file will be stored at the controller

```sh
shell> tree /tmp/fetched/
/tmp/fetched/
└── test_11
    └── container.properties
```

Answer (score 2):

If your file is on the controller, you can use the [`file`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_lookup.html) lookup to get its content.
If the file is on the node, you will have to use something like the [`slurp`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html) module.

Then, when you have the file content, you can use the [`regex_search`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) filter to extract your required text.

1. With the file on the controller:

   ```yaml
   - set_fact:
        com_dkr_container_id: >-
          {{ 
            lookup('file', '/path/to/file') 
              | regex_search('com\.dkr\.container\.id=(.*)', '\1') 
              | first 
          }}
   ```
2. With the file on the node(s):

   ```yaml
   - slurp: 
        src: /path/to/file
      register: file_content

   - set_fact:
        com_dkr_container_id: >-
          {{ 
            file_content.content
              | b64decode
              | regex_search('com\.dkr\.container\.id=(.*)', '\1') 
              | first 
          }}
   ```

Comment: Perfect. Worked on the very first go even as an Ansible beginner. My file is on the controller.